# mkmap crashing when trying to get distance from user location to pin on map

Tags: iphone, distance, mkannotation, mkpinannotationview, userlocation

For some reason whenever i click on my pin the app crashes. there are no errors or warnings in my code. It only happens when i try to get the distance from userLocation to the pin. find my mistake?

```
@implementation FirstViewController
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

[super viewDidLoad];
}
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation   { 

[self showPin];
[self updateLocation];
}
-(IBAction) updateLocation{
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
}
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}  


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];

// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


-(IBAction)setMap:(id)sender{
switch(((UISegmentedControl *)sender).selectedSegmentIndex){
case 0:
{
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
     break;
}
case 1:
{
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
    break;
}
case 2:
{
mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
break;
}

}}
- (void)dealloc
{
[super dealloc];
}
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"pinView"];
if (!pinView) {
    pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pinView"] autorelease];
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;


    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
} else {
    pinView.annotation = annotation;
}
if (annotation == mapView.userLocation){
    return nil; //default to blue dot
}
return pinView;
}
-(IBAction) showPin{
//MOST CODE WILL BE INSERTED HERE!
//instructions

CLLocation *usersLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude];
MKCoordinateRegion region;
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta=0.2;
span.longitudeDelta=0.2;
//ignore above
//always declare location as companyCity 
//if more than one in one city then add a number i.e. companyCity2
//chili in mobile alabama
CLLocationCoordinate2D chiliAuburn = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;

chiliAuburn.latitude = 32.606434 ;
chiliAuburn.longitude = -85.484025;
region.span=span;
region.center=chiliAuburn;
CLLocation *chiliAuburnLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:chiliAuburn.latitude longitude:chiliAuburn.longitude];
if(chiliAuburnAlabama != nil) {
    [mapView removeAnnotation:chiliAuburnAlabama];
    [chiliAuburnAlabama release];
    chiliAuburnAlabama = nil;
}

chiliAuburnAlabama = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:chiliAuburn];
[chiliAuburnAlabama setTitle:@"Chili Yogurt Café"];
double distanceMiles = ([usersLocation distanceFromLocation:chiliAuburnLocation]/1609.334);
[chiliAuburnAlabama setSubTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2fm", distanceMiles]];
//[chiliAuburnAlabama setSubTitle:@"TEST"];
[mapView addAnnotation:chiliAuburnAlabama];
[chiliAuburnAlabama release];
//tutti frutti homewood alabama
CLLocationCoordinate2D tuttifruttiHomewood = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;

tuttifruttiHomewood.latitude = 33.479775 ;
tuttifruttiHomewood.longitude = -86.790977;
region.span=span;
region.center=tuttifruttiHomewood;

if(tuttifruttiHomewoodAlabama != nil) {
    [mapView removeAnnotation:tuttifruttiHomewoodAlabama];
    [tuttifruttiHomewoodAlabama release];
    tuttifruttiHomewoodAlabama = nil;
}

tuttifruttiHomewoodAlabama = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:tuttifruttiHomewood];
[tuttifruttiHomewoodAlabama setTitle:@"Tutti Frutti"];
[tuttifruttiHomewoodAlabama setSubTitle:@"YOUR RATING HERE"];
[mapView addAnnotation:tuttifruttiHomewoodAlabama];


//ignore below
[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
[mapView regionThatFits:region];

}
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {
for(MKAnnotationView *annotationView in views) {
    if(annotationView.annotation == mv.userLocation) {
        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        MKCoordinateSpan span;

        span.latitudeDelta=0.1;
        span.longitudeDelta=0.1; 

        CLLocationCoordinate2D location=mv.userLocation.coordinate;

        region.span=span;
        region.center=location;

        [mv setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
        [mv regionThatFits:region];
    }

}
}



@end
```

GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1518) (Sat Feb 12 02:52:12 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".Attaching to process 23386.
2011-06-02 00:39:46.146 YogurtStoreLocator[23386:207] 32.606434,-85.484025
2011-06-02 00:39:46.148 YogurtStoreLocator[23386:207] 33.479775,-86.790977
2011-06-02 00:39:53.121 YogurtStoreLocator[23386:207] -[NSCFNumber stringByStandardizingWhitespace]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x587b2d0
2011-06-02 00:39:53.123 YogurtStoreLocator[23386:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFNumber stringByStandardizingWhitespace]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x587b2d0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00fca5a9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0111e313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00fcc0bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00f3b966 __*forwarding*** + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00f3b522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit                               0x0034c340 -[UICalloutView setSubtitle:animated:] + 88
    6   UIKit                               0x0034c010 -[UICalloutView setSubtitle:] + 49
    7   MapKit                              0x000bb0ac -[MKAnnotationContainerView _showBubbleForAnnotationView:bounce:scrollToFit:userInitiated:avoid:] + 537
    8   MapKit                              0x000bc3ed -[MKAnnotationContainerView _setSelectedAnnotationView:bounce:pressed:scrollToFit:userInitiated:avoid:] + 653
    9   MapKit                              0x000b54bc -[MKAnnotationContainerView _setSelectedAnnotationView:bounce:pressed:scrollToFit:userInitiated:] + 144
    10  MapKit                              0x0008cab3 -[MKMapView handleTap:] + 459
    11  UIKit                               0x004ad4f2 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:] + 730
    12  UIKit                               0x004a94fe -[UIGestureRecognizer _delayedUpdateGesture] + 47
    13  UIKit                               0x004afafc _UIGestureRecognizerUpdateObserver + 584
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00fab89b **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 27
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00f406e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00f091d7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00f08840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00f08761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x01f071c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x01f07289 GSEventRun + 115
    21  UIKit                               0x0022ac93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    22  YogurtStoreLocator                  0x00002099 main + 121
    23  YogurtStoreLocator                  0x00002015 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)

Comment: will do as soon as it does it again. sometimes instead of crashing it displays "*.local" where the value should be.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious.  Normally when you run an app from Xcode it should output the reason for the crash to the console.  If you were to add that it would help tremendously.

Comment: added crash log. not helpful at all

Comment: And you are sure you are calling this only after you've a valid user location?

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [self showPin];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

and i have a button that refreshes user location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just setting `showsUserLocation` to `YES` isn't sufficient. The map view needs to fetch that data. This is an asynchronous process and the data will be updated only after a while. The delegate is notified of this update via `mapView:didUpdateUseLocation:` method. You should implement that method and make a call to `showPin` only after you've the user location.

Comment: i'm sorry i reall am a retard with this. so i add that into my viewDidLoad or make it its own method? if its own method what do i have it return?

Comment: You will have to adopt the [`delegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html) protocol and implement `mapView:didUpdateUseLocation:` as a different method. You don't have to return anything.

Comment: okay so i have it -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {but what goes here? and how do i only have showpin call after the location is updated?}

Comment: `-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation { [self showPin]; }`

Comment: worked like a charm. and thanks for that link. ill definitely be refferring to that  alot

Comment: oops spoke too soon. got a new error log. ill edit my post. edited code as well. closing down for the night though. thanks for all your help so far

Comment: I'm dealing with the exact same issue here, whenever i click an annotation my app crash with the following error : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFBoolean stringByStandardizingWhitespace]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3a72e528'

Comment: I figured it out !, i was setting the subtitle of the annotaion to a BOOL value ! because i was expecting to get NSString values from the search results im parsing, but for some reason i got a BOOL value. thanks